# Measure of $\varepsilon$- fattening

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a bounded set and let
$$
B(E,\varepsilon)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:\text{dist}(x,E)\leq \varepsilon\}. 
$$
Is it true that
$$
|B(E,\varepsilon)\setminus E)|\leq C\varepsilon
$$
for some constant $C=C(E)$ and $\varepsilon\leq 1$? I know that when $E$ is a convex body, then the result follows from Minkowski - Steiner formula, but what about the general case? Here $|\cdot|$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Just to be clear, you intend here that C depends on E I believe.

Comment: @user24142: I think that's what OP intended by "$C = C(E)$" perhaps.

Comment: My eyes must have passed straight over that... apologies.

Answer (score 3):

In general this is not true.
Consider, for example, in dimension $n=1$ the set $E = \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$.
If you prefer an open set, you can take the set of fat rationals in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Do You know what we should assume on the set E to make this statement true?

Comment: I don't know what are the most general assumptions (other than smoothness or convexity).

Comment: @Isak: maybe this paper can be of your interest: http://cvgmt.sns.it/paper/1391/

Comment: @Isak: Besides the paper Rigel suggested, see also: I. Ya. Oleksiv and N. I. Pesin, [*Finiteness of the Hausdorff measure
of level sets of bounded subsets of a Euclidean space*](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/dc0fd3b5ebcc45820060d73b217977d5/mzm5322.pdf) (Russian), **Matematicheskie
Zametki** 37 #3 (March 1985), 422-431, 462 [[English translation](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01158747) in **Mathematical Notes**
37 #3 (March 1985), 237-242]. [MR 86k:28005](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=790431); [Zbl 573.28010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:03914634)